# How can I have a column in a MySQL database be a function of other columns?

Tags: mysql, alter

I'm working with a database that keeps track of where a reader is in a book. I do this by having a page count column and a current page column.

Is there a way to add a 'progress' column that would be equal to (currentpage/pagecount)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options. You can either create that field on `SELECT`:

```
SELECT book_id, user_id, (currentpage/pagecount) AS progress FROM user_books;
```

Or create a `VIEW`, which will allow you to query it without explicitly stating the operation:

```
CREATE VIEW user_books_progress AS
  (SELECT book_id, user_id, (currentpage/pagecount) AS progress FROM user_books);
```

Then you can just query your view as a normal table:

```
SELECT book_id, user_id, progress FROM user_books_progress;
```

More information about Arithmetic Operators and Views are available in the documentation:

> [11.5.1: Arithmetic Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html)
>   [12.1.12. CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a column to be a function. There are at least two workarounds to this:

- Update your progress column using a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, you'll need one for BEFORE INSERT as well.
- Use a view that calculates the progress column for you.